# how to use ngdeep css class only to a specific component and not all

Tags: css, angular, typescript

How do we use ng deep css class only specific to only for example 1 checkbox and not all checkboxes in my component

for example I only want to use this with my one checkbox and not all checkboxes in my component. how do we do that ? thanks.

I only want to apply it on a specific checkbox . cause in my component there is 5 different checkboxes but I only want to modify 1 checkbox , so the 4 should not be affected.

#checkbox code

```
 <mat-checkbox
                  *ngIf="currentSelectedTenants(subtenant) else currentSubtenants"
                   color="accent"  
                   [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.currentSubtenants"
                   [checked]="currentSelectedTenants(subtenant)" 
                   (change)="changeCurrentSubtenants($event,subtenant)"
                   style="margin-left:10px;">
                  <mat-label class="alter-text-color" style="font-size: 12px;">{{subtenant.subtenantName}}</mat-label>
                  </mat-checkbox>
```

#css

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checkmark-path {
    stroke:rgba(0, 125, 255, 1) !important;
  }
```

Comment: Can't you just add a class to the checkbox you want to change and then do something like ```::ng-deep .special-mark-path > .mat-checkbox-checkmark-path {
    stroke:rgba(0, 125, 255, 1) !important;
  }```

Comment: If you knew where it will be in the component at all times the other way is to use nth-child to select it.

Comment: @RaySuelzer and how do I apply that to my checkbox ?

Comment: like how do I apply it to a checkbox ? like  class="special-mark-path"?